# User/Role/Permission for application using MongoDB and Jackson JSON?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongoose, jackson

I have created three classes user, role, permission. I'm creating an application which is using mongodb and [Jackson JSON](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Example,

```
 User will have Role Object
 Role will have List<Permission> and List<User> Objects
 Permission will have name and description field
```

In `mongoose`, we have DBRef/ref attribute to specify parent, child relationship so that the child entities will be automatically populated on query using `populate()` api

Questions:

1. Do we have annotation in fasterxml similar to DBRef/Ref in mongoose?
2. Is there a way to retrieve all the child objects of the parent in single query?

Comment: Are you using MongoJack?